# Prove that the matrix $ \left[ \begin{array}{ c c } a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right] $ is inherently stable if $a+d<0$ and $ad-bc>0$

Tags: matrices

Prove that the matrix $ \left[   \begin{array}{ c c }      a & b \\      c & d   \end{array} \right] $ is inherently stable if $a+d<0$ and $ad-bc>0$.

I have been asked to consider the system with initial data $y(0)=y_0$:

$\dot{y_1}=ay_1+by_2$

$\dot{y_2}=cy_1+dy_2$

I have started by solving the $\det (A-\lambda I)=0$ and noting the 3 cases where the discriminant can be positive, negative or equal to 0. Is this the right approach?

How would I prove that the eigenvalues for the discriminant being positive are always negative for the conditions $a+d<0$ and $ad-bc>0$?

Comment: The conditions $a+d>0$ and $ad-bc>0$ certainly do not imply that the eigenvalues are real negative or complex with negative real part. Massive typos?

Comment: I think you need $a+d < 0$.  Consider, for example, cases for which $b$ and $c$ are both 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$:-
$$\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc=0$$
Sum of roots = $a+d<0$

Product of roots = $ad-bc>0$

Hence both eigenvalues (roots) are negative.